# Unable to get referer headers working

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, request

I have a proxy set up for a third party service that at the moment looks like this:

```
app.use('/service', (req, res) => {
  let url = `http://www.service.com/endpoint/${config.POSTCODER_KEY}${req.url}`
  req.headers['Referer'] = 'my.domain.com'
  console.log(req.headers['Referer'])
  req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res)
})
```

As you can see I am trying to add Referer header to the request and it seems to be working as `console.log` prints out `'my.domain.com'` however request fails and the error I get back from the service is 403 unauthorised referring to Referer header. When I inspect network in inspector tools my referer is displayed as localhost.

I am testing this in Postman api client (https://www.getpostman.com) by setting Referer to my white listed domain and it works. I'm not sure why it uses localhost with express.

Comment: Try adding the protocol `http://my.domain.com`

Comment: @mplungjan this is just an example, I'm setting this to my actual domain. Could you expand on protocol suggestion? As prepending http nor https works

Comment: Perhaps the service only allows certain domains

Comment: @mplungjan indeed I am testing this in Postman api client (https://www.getpostman.com) by setting Referer to my white listed domain and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping streams together only transfers the data in those streams. Headers are not a part of that. When you `req.pipe(request(url))` you're only writing the request body to the proxied request. If you want to set the headers used for the proxied request, you have to pass them to `request`, like:

```
req.pipe(request({ url: url, headers: req.headers })).pipe(res);
```

However, as noted in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39080653/2050455), you will also need to properly set the headers on `res` when the proxied response arrives.

Comment: Thank you, you have been explaining these issues very well.